# Error en parametros

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Tengo la siguiente consulta, tengo que mostrar en un gridview los registros pero me marca este error,"La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto."

tengo parámetros en string y uno entero

```
App_Data.DataSet1TableAdapters.PS_USR_ConsultaExternaTableAdapter adapter = new App_Data.DataSet1TableAdapters.PS_USR_ConsultaExternaTableAdapter();

            adapter.GetData("", "", "", int.Parse(this.TextBox1.Text));
this.gvbuscar.DataSource = adapter.GetData("", "", "", int.Parse(this.TextBox1.Text));
            this.gvbuscar.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que el problema al tratar de convertir el contenido de un `TextBox` a entero, en algunos casos al parecer el contenido no es  númerico y provoca el error:

```
int.Parse(this.TextBox1.Text)
```

puedes validar mediante `int.TryParse()`:

Ejemplo:

```
    //Si el valor no es númerico asigna un default con valor de 0.
    int valorTextBox = int.TryParse(this.TextBox1.Text, out valorTextBox) ? valorTextBox: 0;

    adapter.GetData("", "", "", valorTextBox);
    this.gvbuscar.DataSource = adapter.GetData("", "", "", valorTextBox));
    this.gvbuscar.DataBind();
```

Comment: En un textbox tengo escribir tal nombre que esté en la db, al momento de hacer clic en el botón tiene que cargar datos en el gridview, entonces agregué el textbox, el valorTextBox puedo agregar 0? o por que lo tengo que cambiar?

Comment: aquí int.Parse(this.TextBox1.Text) estas tratando de convertir una cadena contenida en el textbox a entero, si TextBox1 tiene dentro un valor no númerico, eso provoca e problema. Con la validacion que sugiero en caso de no contener un valor o contener un valor no numerico, por default usaria el valor de 0, únicamente en esa situación.

Comment: Muy bien, entonces en dónde dice valortextbox le agrego el 0? y donde dice valor igual?

Comment: No, simplemente agrega la validación como esta en mi respuesta, prueba y me comentas.

Comment: Preguntaba porque lo hice cómo habías dicho y me marca error:                    "valor) ? valor"    en las dos palabras de valor, me dice el error que no existe en el contexto

Comment: Perdón Alexandra, no escribi correctamente la variable, he editado, debe ser:  int valorTextBox = int.TryParse(this.TextBox1.Text, out valorTextBox) ? valorTextBox: 0;